# How long does it take the page to load or response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I want to know how much does it take the page to load and respond to the request that was given to it, in other meaning how much does it take to give an err_time_out.
I have a page that takes a little bit time to respond and i want to modify the duration of the page to respond without giving an err_time_out.
And if i did it with ajax does it will last longer ?

Comment: how long is a piece of string?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome DevTools.

Press F12 at chrome and go network, after you submit a request, you can see your request, response there and the detail.

Therefore you can see how much time take of your request and tune it.

Comment: I know that already but it changes from request to other one can tale longer than the usual it's not fixed, how to control the duration of the response ?

Comment: the duration of the response handled by the server side. And it contains a lot of factor like network speed etc. If you want to set the timeout on the server side you can config it in the service side. Or reduce the thing that the request handling.